# Git rebase: Git forgets that I already rebased

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am doing a major refactor on a branch that was started months ago, then work stopped.  It took a LONG time to rebase onto the current master.

Now someone changed a couple of files and I want to integrate those changes.

I started to rebase, but it wants me to merge those 1000 conflicts again!!!

Is there some way to tell git that my branch is already merged with that previous master?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Have you gone through the [tour]?

Answer (score 0):

**Cherry pick** the fresh change. Don’t merge the whole thing again!

You might need to explain the details more: what branch were thise changes on, etc.?

Comment: These changes were on the onewar branch, branched off of master.
Like:

`M1 - M2 - ...       - M100 - M101`
`   \                             \ `
`   O1 ... O50              \`
`                                   P1... P50 ... P100`

Comment: *Edit* your post to include more info; don’t just state it in comments (or comments to answers!).

Comment: Please ignore that last one...  I don't know how to make diagrams here..

Onewar and its 50 changes were branched off Master M1

Then master had 100 changes

I rebased Onewar onto M100 and now Onewar has 90 changes, the original 50 plus resolution of all the conflicts. Now someone has made a few changes to create M101

Maybe rebasing was a mistake and I should have merged...  Can I somehow tell git that my branch is merged with M100, so I can get M101 changes without replaying all O1..90?

Yes, I can cherry pick every change from now on. That seems ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.
I'll just

- checkout M100 in a separate folder
- make a NEW branch
- Copy all my changes into this folder
- then merge the new changes of master into it
- work on the NEW branch